# Does VSCode use blocking communication with LSP

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm playing around Language Server Protocol. After playing around for sometime I can see two way to communicate with the Language server, which is blocking sockets and non-blocking sockets.

By blocking socket I mean sending request and block until response. This is easy but It will block the UI once I use it in GUI application. Another one is using async/non-blocking sockets. This is a bit complex and might require some callback/event mechanism.

Now my question is which way does VSCode use to communicate with LSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [node language server implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node) used by many extensions uses non-blocking communications. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node/tree/master/jsonrpc). It uses nodejs streams and the `net` module